# How to read current displayed frame of animation?

Tags: ios, objective-c, watchkit

There is a image and a button on Watchkit interface. 
Image animation starts and i press the button, animation pause.
Now i need to read which frame is currently displayed.

Is it possible?

Comment: I don't believe there is a way to get the current displayed image as a part of a animation sequence. There are other ways to solve this though, depending on what you want to achieve. Once you know the length of your animation and the speed it runs at, you could use a timer to figure out where you are.

Answer (score 0):

As Aleksander said it is not possible to get the right frame name from your animation. However you could divide your animation in parts and call the next part when the previous part is done animating. You could try my framework I just released to ease your work with animations and also have a completion handling.

[TimelineKit - Framework](https://github.com/DevAndArtist/TimelineKit)

```
func startAnimationWithRange(range: Range) 
{
    Timeline.with(identifier: "MyAnimation", delay: 0.0, duration: 2.0, execution: {

        // put your animation code in here
        // assumed animation time == duration (2.0 seconds)

    }, completion: {

        // check if your button was clicked and return or call the next animation part

        self.startAnimationWithRange(range: nextAnimationRange)
    }).start
}
```

Check the TimelineKit.swift source file for documentation. Feedback is also welcome. :)